# JMeter- property values are not substituted when running from CLI

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I am currently using JMeter 5.1.1 on a Mac and have developed a very simple JMeter project to test out property value substitutions via Command Line. My JMeter project is pretty simple with a Dummy Sampler trying to print out the following

```
${__P(resources.folder)}, ${__P(propertiesfile)} and ${__property(propertiesfile)}
```

[Link to JMeter project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLpwS.png)

I am trying to run this project via CLI using the command

```
jmeter -n -t TestProj.jmx -l jmeter/TestProjResults.jtl -j jmeter/TestProj.log -Dresources.folder=/Users/h244955/Coding/bga/spogdashboard/tests/perf -Dpropertiesfile=baforgeperfproperties
```

The values are not getting substituted and I am seeing the following in the log:

> **2019-10-22 20:48:09,531 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: ${__P(resources.folder)}
>   ${__P(propertiesfile)}
>   ${__property(propertiesfile)}
>   2019-10-22 20:48:09,533 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Not running version, return raw function string**
>   2019-10-22 20:48:09,533 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: Replacement result: ${__P(resources.folder)}
>   ${__P(propertiesfile)}
>   ${__property(propertiesfile)}
>   2019-10-22 20:48:09,534 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: Dummy Sampler used to simulate requests and responses
>   without actual network activity. This helps debugging tests.
>   2019-10-22 20:48:09,534 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: Replacement result: Dummy Sampler used to simulate requests and responses
>   without actual network activity. This helps debugging tests.
>   2019-10-22 20:48:09,534 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: ${__Random(50,500)}
>   2019-10-22 20:48:09,534 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Not running version, return raw function string
>   2019-10-22 20:48:09,534 DEBUG o.a.j.e.u.ValueReplacer: Replacement result: ${__Random(50,500)}

However, when I run this project from GUI with the help of declaring the same properties using a JSR223 Sampler, the values are getting substituted in the Dummy Sampler as expected. I tried looking around for answers for the highlighted log above, but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [override JMeter property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) using -`J`:

```
 jmeter -n -t TestProj.jmx -Jresources.folder=/Users/h244955/Coding/bga/spogdashboard/tests/perf -Jpropertiesfile=baforgeperfproperties -l jmeter/TestProjResults.jtl -j jmeter/TestProj.log
```

> -D[prop_name]=[value]
>   defines a java system property value.
>   -J[prop_name]=[value]
>   defines a local JMeter property.

To add additional JMeter property file use `-q`

> ```
> -q, --addprop <argument>
>     additional JMeter property file(s)
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, even when trying this way I am still having issues. Maybe it's the way I am calling the properties. I am trying the following in JSR223

`log.info("======Variable Value: " + ${__P(foo)}); //Returns an error since it searches for variable "bar"
log.info("======Variable Value: " + props.get("foo")); //Returns null`

Comment: @ragz if you want additional property file use  `-q baforgeperfproperties`

Comment: Do these come in as system properties or Jmeter properties?

Comment: Also, is there a difference between how we can reference system properties vs Jmeter properties in something like an "If Controller"?

Comment: @Ragz JMeter properties, you get both properties the same

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue:

[image]

so my expectation is that your JMeter installation is broken somehow, i.e. make sure that [`ApacheJMeter_functions.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions/5.1.1) file is present in "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation

1. Make sure to get JMeter from the [official downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and [check the downloaded archive integrity](http://www.apache.org/info/verification.html), check [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans/) article for details.
2. Make sure to launch JMeter from its "bin" folder, to wit

   ```
   cd /path/where/jmeter/lives/bin 
   ./jmeter -Dpropertiesfile=baforgeperfproperties -n -t test.jmx ....
   ```

   this `./jmeter` bit is important to ensure that you launch JMeter from the current folder, not from another folder in your MacOS [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Dmitri T. I tried your suggestion and I am able to print "Parameters". However, when I do the following, I see the issues:    

`log.info("======Variable Value: " + ${__P(foo)}); //Returns an error since it searches for variable "bar" .    
log.info("======Variable Value: " + props.get("foo")); //Returns null`

Comment: Also, is there a difference between how we can reference system properties vs Jmeter properties in something like an "If Controller"?